# Ignore Angular2 component stylesheets with ExtractTextPlugin in webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using the [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) plugin to inject `<script>` tags into a template file for the chunks that webpack generates. I also have a few global stylesheets that I want to dynamically add to the `<head>` section of my HTML template. For that, I am also using the html-webpack-plugin as follows (the `app` entry/chunk is the relevant one in this case).

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './ts/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './ts/vendor.ts',
        'app': './ts/app.ts'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['to-string-loader', ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].[contenthash].css'),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            bootstrap: 'bootstrap'
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'app',
            filename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].min.js',
            chunks: ['app']
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].min.js',
            chunks: ['vendor']
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'polyfills',
            filename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].min.js',
            chunks: ['polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'my-template.html',
            filename: 'my-template.html',
            inject: 'body',
            hash: false
        }),
    ]
};
```

Below is the `app.ts` file, where I have added a `require` statement for each stylesheet that I would like to include in my template (they are being merged together into a single stylesheet).

```
require('main.css');
require('misc.css');

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Essentially this works well, but the catch is that I am using this configuration for an Angular2 application, which is composed of components which may have associated stylesheets, like in this example.

```
@Component({
    styleUrls: [
        'my-stylesheet.css'
    ]
})
export class MyComponent { ... }
```

Building the application would normally result in a ton of HTTP calls for these stylesheets for the components, so to solve this, I have pulled the stylesheets directly into the components by using [angular2-template-loader](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader). This loader works as follows.

> The angular2-template-loader searches for templateUrl and styleUrls
>   declarations inside of the Angular 2 Component metadata and replaces
>   the paths with the corresponding require statement.

The problem with this is that besides the two stylesheets that are added to the `app.ts` entrypoint, webpack also includes every stylesheet that is referenced from my Angular2 components. Because it goes through the dependencies of the application and finds the `require` statements added by angular2-template-loader. This is undesirable, because I want those stylesheets to be local to the components they belong to, i.e. be inline in the JS.

Therefore I need a way to *only* include the stylesheets that I `require` directly in my entrypoints, perhaps by somehow excluding the component stylesheets. The problem is that in both cases, the file have the `.css` extension, so they both pass the test for the `extract-text-plugin`. I took a look at the documentation of the loaders/plugins, but I couldn't find anything that would solve my problem.

So what I want is to add a `app.[contenthash].css` file to my template file (this part works), but *excluding the stylesheets referenced in my Angular2 components* (included because of angular2-template-loader).

How can I prevent these Angular2 component stylesheets from being included in the stylesheet that is added to my HTML template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you have the following folder structure:

[image]

So all my components are located inside *app* folder.

**main.ts**

```
require('main.css');
require('misc.css');

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**/app/app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>My Angular 2 App</h1>`,
  styleUrls: ['my-stylesheet.css']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Then your solution might look like:

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /app\\.+\.css$/, <== add this (exclude all styles from app folder)
  loaders: ['to-string-loader', ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')]
},
{
  test: /app\\.+\.css$/,
  loader: 'raw'  <== use raw loader for these files
}
```

Comment: Ah, that looks pretty good! I will give it a spin as soon as possible and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I tried playing around with this, but couldn't get it to work. First of all, my CSS files are located at `public/css`, where the stylesheets for the components are located at `public/css/components/**/*.css`. I tried to exclude `/public\/css\/components/` in the first loader and used `raw` for the second, along with a lot of different tests and excludes, with various different errors. I am not sure if I am messing up with the paths/regex or what the issue is. If you could provide an example with the before mentioned paths, that would really be awesome, because I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Try `/public\\css\\components/` or `/css\\components/`

Comment: After trying out a ton of combinations, I managed to get it to work. Although I had no success with exactly what you suggested, it was close enough to get me on the right track, so thanks a lot for that! I have added an answer with my solution for anyone who may need it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could give webpack a hint to differentiate the CSS files by using two separate name patterns. Say you name all files that should be included by angular2-template-loader with suffix `.tl` (short for template loader, e.g. `mycss.tl.css`) and the other ones with suffix `.pt` (short for platform, e.g. `main.pt.css`), then you can write the webpack config as follows:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.pt\.css$/,
                loaders: ['to-string-loader', ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')]
            },
            {
                test: /\.tl\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
```

Your component definition then looks like

```
@Component({
    styleUrls: [
        'my-stylesheet.tl.css'
    ]
})
export class MyComponent { ... }
```

whereas in `app.ts` you place

```
require('main.pt.css');
require('misc.pt.css');

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

angular2-template-loader then still wraps the css paths with `require` calls but based on your config you can have a different set of loaders for the css files.

Comment: I was actually thinking of doing something like that, but it seemed like a hack in my mind, so I wondered if there was a better solution out there. I will play a bit around with it and see what I can come up with. Thank you for your answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested, I did manage to solve the issue, inspired by @yurzui's answer.

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: [helpers.root('public', 'css', 'components')],
            loaders: ['to-string-loader', ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: [helpers.root('public', 'css', 'components')],
            loaders: ['raw-loader']
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above example, I am using a custom helper of mine to assemble the path to the directories. You could do this somehow else, but here is my helper anyways (taken from Angular2's documentation).

```
var path = require('path');
var _root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..'); // This file is stored within a webpack subdirectory in my case

function root(args) {
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return path.join.apply(path, [_root].concat(args));
}

exports.root = root;
```

To use it, simply require it in your webpack configuration.

```
var helpers = require('./helpers');
```

I hope this helps someone.